# Replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank

Tags: beginner, c, strings

> ***K&R* 1.9 exercise:**
>
> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

Is this correct and proper code? Could I have put `c` and `inspace` on a single line?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /*initializes c and inspace. */
    int c;
    int inspace;

    /*sets inspace = 0*/
    inspace = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            if(inspace ==0)
            {
                inspace = 1;
                putchar(c);
            }
        }

        if(c != ' ')
        {
            inspace = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using the latest Ubuntu distro 64 bit.

Comment: What is your operating system? How do you launch your program? On unix-like operating systems, one way to do it is to type this in a terminal (without the $): $ `echo "a really   nice input  !" | ./your_executable`

Comment: You should get rid of your comments.  They do not add anything to the program.  The first one is actually wrong (you're not initializing anything, you're declaring).  You CAN initialize in the declaration though by using `int inspace = 0;`, turning two lines into one.

Answer (score 10):

Looks fine to me.  But I would replace

```
if (inspace == 0)
```

with

```
if (!inspace)
```

for stylistic reasons. And

```
if (c != ' ')
```

with

```
else
```

because there is no need to compare `c` again: you already know it isn't equal to a space because of the first `if` statement.

Also the code inside {...} after `main` should be indented over.

Comment: What does !inspace mean?

Comment: '!' means 'not'.  In a C boolean expression, 0 always means false and non-zero means true.  So '!0' means true.

Comment: In your case, if inspace really was equal to 0, then !inspace = true. I would use this style if it makes your code easier to read but it can take time to get used to.

Answer (score 7):

- Comments should not state the obvious:

  ```
  /*initializes c and inspace. */
  int c;
  int inspace;

  /*sets inspace = 0*/
  inspace = 0;
  ```

  The first comment is also misleading because both variables are being *declared* (no initial value set), not initialized (initial value set).  Comments are supposed to stay in sync with code, and misleading comments do detract from that.

  Furthermore, there's no need to declare and then assign to `inspace`.  Initializing right away will also help keep variables in closer scope, which is encouraged.

  ```
  int inspace = 0;
  ```
- Prefer to use [`isspace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) to check if a character is a space.  Since you're checking if a character is *not* a space, use it with `!`.

  ```
  if (!isspace(c))
  ```